# run go unit test tip /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found

Tags: go, gcc

Compile and run on one machine `go test -c -run TestChannelReportCsv` get `mqworker.test` Then I ran on another machine `mqworker.test`
The following issues have arisen

```bash
bash-4.2$ ./mqworker.test 
./mqworker.test: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./mqworker.test)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Based on your issue, it seems to be a library version incompatibility. You can try updating the libstdc++ library on the target machine or recompile the binary on the target machine to ensure it links to the correct library version. If you still encounter problems or need further assistance, feel free to ask. I hope it help.